# Authorize.net ARB SSL certificate issue

Tags: php, ssl, ssl-certificate, authorize.net, authorize.net-arb

I am trying to create Authorize.net recurring subscriptions using PHP. 
I installed Composer, then used the composer.json as shown here https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sample-code-php/blob/master/composer.json to install the Authorize.net SDK.
Now I am trying to create a subscription on my sandbox account using the code found here: https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sample-code-php/blob/master/RecurringBilling/create-subscription.php.

When I try to run this, it gives me the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Error getting valid response from api. Check log file for error details' in /home/tpmadmin/public_html/vendor/authorizenet/authorizenet/lib/net/authorize/api/controller/base/ApiOperationBase.php:122 Stack trace: #0 /home/tpmadmin/public_html/vendor/authorizenet/authorizenet/lib/net/authorize/api/controller/base/ApiOperationBase.php(104): net\authorize\api\controller\base\ApiOperationBase->execute('https://apitest...') #1 /home/tpmadmin/public_html/test.php(58): net\authorize\api\controller\base\ApiOperationBase->executeWithApiResponse('https://apitest...') #2 {main} thrown in /home/tpmadmin/public_html/vendor/authorizenet/authorizenet/lib/net/authorize/api/controller/base/ApiOperationBase.php on line 122

I checked the error log and it's showing me the following:

```
Tue, 13 Oct 2015 06:51:05 +0000:CURL ERROR: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
Tue, 13 Oct 2015 06:51:22 +0000: Request Serialization Begin
Tue, 13 Oct 2015 06:51:22 +0000: Request  Serialization End
Tue, 13 Oct 2015 06:51:22 +0000: Url: https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api
Tue, 13 Oct 2015 06:51:22 +0000:Request to AnetApi: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ARBCreateSubscriptionRequest xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
  <merchantAuthentication>
    <name><![CDATA[MY_API_LOGIN]]></name>
    <transactionKey><![CDATA[MY_TRANSACTION_KEY]]></transactionKey>
  </merchantAuthentication>
  <refId><![CDATA[ref1444719082]]></refId>
  <subscription>
    <name><![CDATA[Sample Subscription]]></name>
    <paymentSchedule>
      <interval>
        <length>1</length>
        <unit><![CDATA[months]]></unit>
      </interval>
      <startDate><![CDATA[2020-08-30]]></startDate>
      <totalOccurrences>12</totalOccurrences>
      <trialOccurrences>1</trialOccurrences>
    </paymentSchedule>
    <amount>10.29</amount>
    <trialAmount>0.00</trialAmount>
    <payment>
      <creditCard>
        <cardNumber><![CDATA[4111111111111111]]></cardNumber>
        <expirationDate><![CDATA[2020-12]]></expirationDate>
      </creditCard>
    </payment>
    <billTo>
      <firstName><![CDATA[John]]></firstName>
      <lastName><![CDATA[Smith]]></lastName>
    </billTo>
  </subscription>
</ARBCreateSubscriptionRequest>

Sending 'XML' Request type
Tue, 13 Oct 2015 06:51:22 +0000:Sending http request via Curl
Tue, 13 Oct 2015 06:51:23 +0000:Response from AnetApi: 


Tue, 13 Oct 2015 06:51:23 +0000:CURL ERROR: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`
```

Note: in the message above I replaced my actual API_LOGIN_ID and TRANSACTION_KEY. The real message has the correct login information.

I don't know much about SSL certificates or what could be causing this. I've searched for hours on Google with no luck. Any help or advice would be awesome!

UPDATE: It's working on the live account, but not on the Sandbox account -_-

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, but I'm only wanting to authorize.

So, for my situation with authOnly SANDBOX requests I modified HttpClient to include curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

If I were doing more than authOnly requests, I'd probably use a different Authorize API (CIM via SOAP, for example)

One of my peers believes that PROD won't give the issue and shouldn't require curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false) but I haven't tested that thoroughly.

Comment: I've tried this solution with no luck thanks for the response though

Comment: I added this in at the end of a stack of curl_setopt functions inside the _sendRequest method and it totally worked. 
It was absolutely a lack of proper SSL certificate for the SANDBOX environment. 

Who requires a proper SSL cert for a sandbox environment?! authorize dot net apparently